# CSS transition position absolute from one edge to the other

Tags: css, html, css-transitions, css-position

How can I transition a HTML div with an absolute position (`right: 0; bottom: 0px`) to another edge (`left: 0px; top: 0px;`).

I have tried the following code, however, transition with absolute elements only seems to work when using either left/top, or right/bottom.

What is the preferred way to do that in HTML5?

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("my-box");
ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
 ele.classList.toggle("clicked");
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.box.clicked {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id='my-box'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep using the `top` and `right` on the clicked below. Just use a calc to position them like below

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("my-box");
ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
 ele.classList.toggle("clicked");
});
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.box.clicked {
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
  right: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id='my-box'>

</div>
```

Comment: Are there any performance panalties or other disadvantages to using `calc`?

Comment: I don't think anything towards calc specifically. I believe ideally you should only transition opacity & transform if you want silky smooth transitions. The problem here though is transform is relative to the element you're on. If you're doing this across the screen Aykut's method above works fine but if you aren't able to use `vw` or `vh` then it will be close to impossible to accomplish it with just transforms so you will have to resort to `top` and `right`

Answer (score 1):

change your .clicked class as

```
.box.clicked {
  transform:translate(calc(-100vw + 100px) ,calc(100vh - 100px))
}
```